# Highlighting items when selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a list of elements (divs) which all have the same background color (white). Now, I want to make the background color change (to blue) once they are clicked. Thing is this, only one can be highlighted at a time.

So, let's say you click `div1`, and it turns blue. If you click `div2`, it needs to make `div1` turn white and then `div2` turn blue.

Sort of a selecting method, no?

Is there a stand-alone method of doing this?

Comment: Sort of like the :focus method for inputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This:

**Jquery Code:**

```
$('div').bind('click',function(){
$('div').removeClass('selected');//remove selected class from previously added div
$(this).addClass('selected');//add class to current div
})
```

**CSS:**

```
.selected{
background-color:blue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this ...

```
<style type="text/css"><!--
   #menu_top {
  list-style:none;
  width:100%;
  float:left; 
  margin:8px 0;
  border-bottom:8px solid #60CBFF;
  font:normal 11px/22px arial,helvetica,sans-serif;
    }

    #menu_top li, #menu_top a {
    float:left;
    height:22px;
    }

    #menu_top li {
     margin-left:4px;
    }


    #menu_top a {
       background: none repeat scroll 0 0 white;
       color: #000000;
       padding: 0 8px;
       position: relative;
       text-decoration: none;
    }

    #menu_top a:active,
     #menu_top a:focus,
      #menu_top a:hover {
        background: none repeat scroll 0 0 blue;
     }


 </style>
```

and HTML code is ..

```
<ul id="menu_top">
  <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Download</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Career</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
```

You can check my [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/pU4dN/2/) also.

Answer (score 0):

For a library agnostic solution, you could use something like this:

```
<style>
    .clickable {
        background-color: #eee;
        height: 30px;
        margin: 10px;
    }
</style>

<div>
    <div class="clickable"></div>
    <div class="clickable"></div>
    <div class="clickable"></div>
</div>

<script>
    var clickables = document.getElementsByClassName('clickable');

    var resetSiblings = function () {
        for (var i = clickables.length - 1; i >= 0 ; i--)
            clickables[i].style.backgroundColor = '#eee';
    };

    var clickHandler = function (ev) {
        resetSiblings();
        ev.target.style.backgroundColor = '#00f'
    };

    for (var i = clickables.length - 1; i >= 0 ; i--)
        clickables[i].addEventListener("click", clickHandler, false);
</script>
```